# subsonic setup issue

Tags: namespaces, subsonic, installation

I've setup subsonic 2.2 on a new website project.
after going through all the needed steps, I've managed to make it roll.
so I could see the DAL namespace with all the generated names for tables in the visual studio intellisense.

one thing is wrong, which is the Subsonic namespace itself, which I cannnot add to the page,
in the "using subsonic" line. or even call subsonic within the code itself.
"Subsonic" is gone.

I've registered the subsonic.dll as a reference already so all supposed to be ok.
I'm using visual web developer 2008, and got already few websites using subsonic.

any suggestions? 
thanks,

Shahar Weinstein.